# Cómo multiplicar dos matrices en Java

Tags: java, matrices

estoy haciendo un código que recibe dos matrices y las multiplica retornando una matriz nueva, pero no se como hacer para guardar los valores de la multiplicación en la matriz nueva

```
 public static int[][] multiplicación (int [][] A, int [][] B){
   // columnas de la matriz A
   int n= A[0].length;
   // filas de la matriz A
   int m= A.length;
   // filas de la matriz B
   int n2= B.length;
   // columnas de la matriz B
   int o= B[0].length;
   // nueva matriz 
   int [][] C= new int [m][o];
   // se comprueba si las matrices se pueden multiplicar
   if (n==n2){
     for (int i=0; i<n-1;i++){
         int a=0;
        for (int j=0; j<n2-1;j++){
         //aqui se multiplica la matriz
         a= a+(A[i][j]*B[j][i]);
        }

        }
    }
   /**
    *  si no se cumple la condición se retorna una matriz vacía
    */
   return C;
}
```

Comment: Debajo de la linea a= a+(A[i][j]*B[j][i]);  ubicada deltro del segundo for creo que debes poner C[i][j] = a;

Comment: no funciono ingrese la siguientes dos  matrices {{1,2,-3},{4,0,-2}} la cual seria la matriz A y {{3,1},{2,4},{-1,5}} que seria la B, la multiplicación de ambas debería ser {{10,-6},{14,-6}}, pero el programa me retorna {{3,7},{4,4}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

📖 Primeramente, para poder multiplicar dos matrices, éstas deben cumplir una condición:

> Usted solo puede multiplicar dos matrices si sus dimensiones son compatibles, lo que significa que el número de columnas en la primera matriz es igual al número de renglones en la segunda matriz. Si *A* es una matriz *a × b* y *B* es una matriz *b × c* , el producto *AB* es una matriz *a × c*.

Y se realiza de la siguiente forma:

> La definición de la multiplicación de matrices indica una multiplicación renglón-por-columna, donde las entradas en el renglón *i <sup>th</sup>* de *A* son multiplicadas por las entradas correspondientes en el renglón *j <sup>th</sup>* de *B* y luego se suman los resultados.

💻 Esto es, en código:

```
public static int[][] multiply(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int[][] c = new int[a.length][b[0].length];
    // se comprueba si las matrices se pueden multiplicar
    if (a[0].length == b.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++) {
                    // aquí se multiplica la matriz
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * si no se cumple la condición se retorna una matriz vacía
     */
    return c;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = { { 1, 2, -3 }, { 4, 0, -2 } };
    int[][] b = { { 3, 1 }, { 2, 4 }, { -1, 5 } };
    int[][] c = multiply(a, b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
}
```

Salida:

```
[[10, -6], [14, -6]]
```

---

📓 ***Referencias***

- Multiplicación de matrices. *Varsity Tutors.* Recuperado de https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/spanish/topics/matrix-multiplication
- Gupta, M. Arrays.deepToString() in Java with Example. *GeeksforGeeks.* Recuperado de http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-deeptostring-in-java-with-example/

Answer (score 2):

Te falta agregar un for para recorrer cada columna de la matriz B y realizar la operación `a=a+A[i][k]*B[k][j];`, aparte de que no tienes que poner `n-1` ni `n2-1` en tus for ya que así no recorres todas las posiciones.

```
   public static int[][] multiplicación (int [][] A, int [][] B){
       // columnas de la matriz A
       int n= A[0].length;
       // filas de la matriz A
       int m= A.length;
       // filas de la matriz B
       int n2= B.length;
       // columnas de la matriz B
       int o= B[0].length;
       // nueva matriz 
       int [][] C= new int [m][o];
       // se comprueba si las matrices se pueden multiplicar
       if (n==n2){
         for (int i=0; i<n;i++){

            for (int j=0; j<n2;j++){
             //aqui se multiplica la matriz
              int a=0;
              for(int k=0;k<o;k++){
                  a=a+A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                }
           C[i][j]=a;     
            }

            }
        }
       /**
        *  si no se cumple la condición se retorna una matriz vacía
        */
       return C;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * método para multiplicar las matrices A y B
 * 
 * @param matrizA
 * @param matrizB
 * @return Matriz solución AxB
 */
public static double[][] multiplicarMatrices(double matrizA[][], double matrizB[][]) {

    double matrizResultado[][] = new double[matrizA.length][matrizA[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrizA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrizA[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k=0;k<matrizA[0].length;k++) { 
                matrizResultado[i][j]+= (matrizA[i][k] * matrizB[k][j]);    
            }
        }

    }

    return matrizResultado;
}
```

Comment: Responder con solo codigo se considera de baja calidad.

Comment: Hola Juan Pablo, por favor edita tu respuesta para añadir una breve descripción de qué es lo que hace el código y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Saludos, tal como te comentan es mejor agregar detalles al respecto de como soluciona el problema tu respuesta para un mejor entender..!!

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco me mandaron este ejercicio y lo hice de esta manera donde puedes ingresar las filas y columnas de las matrices para ser multiplicadas.

**Declaración de variables :**

```
int filaA = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numero de filas para la matriz A"));
        int columnaA = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numero de columnas para la matriz A"));

        int filaB = columnaA;
        int columnaB = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numero de filas para la matriz B"));


        int matrizA[][] = new int[filaA][columnaA];
        int matrizB[][] = new int[filaB][columnaB];
        int matrizResultante[][] = new int[filaA][columnaB];

        String _matrizA = "Matriz A: \n";
        String _matrizB = "Matriz B: \n";
        String _matrizResultante = "Matriz A*B: \n";
```

**LLENAR DATOS A LA MATRIZ**

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < filaA ; fila++) {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < columnaA; columna++) {
            matrizA[fila][columna] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese valor en A["+fila+"]["+columna+"]"));
        }
    }

    for (int fila = 0; fila < filaB ; fila++) {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < columnaB; columna++) {
            matrizB[fila][columna] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese valor en B["+fila+"]["+columna+"]"));
        }
    }
```

**Algoritmo de calculo :**

```
for (int filaMatrizResultado = 0; filaMatrizResultado < filaA; filaMatrizResultado++) {
        for (int columnaMatrizResultado = 0; columnaMatrizResultado < columnaB; columnaMatrizResultado++) {
            int rpta = 0;
            for (int ncolumnA = 0; ncolumnA < columnaA ; ncolumnA++) {
                rpta += matrizA[filaMatrizResultado][ncolumnA] * matrizB[ncolumnA][columnaMatrizResultado];
            }
            matrizResultante[filaMatrizResultado][columnaMatrizResultado] = rpta;
        }
}
```

**MENSAJES DE SALIDA Y GRÁFICA DE LA MATRIZ**

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < filaA ; fila++) {
    _matrizA +="| ";
    for (int c = 0; c < columnaA; c++) {
        _matrizA +=" " + matrizA[fila][c] +" ";
    }
    _matrizA +=" |\n";
}


for (int fila = 0;fila < filaB ; fila++) {
    _matrizB +="| ";
    for (int c = 0; c < columnaB; c++) {
        _matrizB +=" " +matrizB[fila][c] +" ";
    }
    _matrizB +=" |\n";
}



for (int fila = 0; fila < filaA ; fila++) {
    _matrizResultante +="| ";
    for (int c = 0; c < columnaB; c++) {
        _matrizResultante +=" " +matrizResultante[fila][c] +" ";
    }
    _matrizResultante +=" |\n";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, _matrizA+ _matrizB+_matrizResultante);
```